# How to perform bulk actions with Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, bulk

In Active Admin, is it possible to add a checkbox to each item in an index page (this isn't hard), and add some kind of menu to perform bulk actions on all selected items, like delete all selected items at once.

I can't find an other way to do this than to create a custom page, but I'd rather not do that; seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible, see this article: [Active Admin 0.5.0 has been released! Batch Actions](https://web.archive.org/web/20190114124104/http://reverbhq.com/blog/2012/08/activeadmin-0-5-0-is-released/)

Answer (score 21):

It works using the mentioned branch, but not on a custom panel, from what I'm seeing.

We have it working on an index:

```
index do
    selectable_column
    column :id
    column :name
```

But can't make it work on a show:

```
panel "Children - Process Nodes" do
  text_node link_to "New", new_admin_process_node_path(:parent_id => department_node.id)
  unless department_node.children.empty?
    table_for department_node.children do 
      column :id
      column :name
```

selectable_column inside table_for doesn't seem to work.

> undefined local variable or method `selectable_column' for #

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is no way to do this using the master ActiveAdmin branch but checkout the [Batch Edit API branch](https://github.com/mattvague/active_admin/tree/270_batch_edit_api)

Comment: Don't have the time to look into it right now, but that sounds just right. Will give it a try this weekend I hope.